# Query Cancelling out remaining queries

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a link inside of the users profile that takes them to their blog, but after this string it no longer displays any other data that is SQL related after this point. Does anyone know why this might happen?

```
      <?php
                $query = "SELECT nicename FROM user WHERE username='$_SESSION[admin_login]'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $link = "<a href='blogs.php?user=" . $row['nicename'] . "'>My Blog</a>";
    echo $link;
mysqli_free_result($result);
      ?>
```

Removed the unneeded While and Posted Next SQL Query.

```
 <?php
$query = "SELECT header FROM pages WHERE name='Index'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row['header'];
mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Please show us also the next code. You should not use `while` statement in this case because you will always get just one result so you should set directly `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)` without using `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link = "<a href='blogs.php?user=" . $row['nicename'] . "'>My Blog</a>";
...
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

It seems you're overriding `$link` with a string so in your next call to `mysqli_query` you pass a string as first argument instead of a `mysqli` instance.

Comment: Wasn't putting the two together. Thanks.